# blogger custom domain redirection not working..!

Tags: dns, blogger

Hope you all will be fine,I just purchased a domain for a blogger account...and have already added it to the blog but the problem is that the site doesn't load without www. and also i have checked to the options available as that redirect domainname.com to www.domainname.com..

Infact I am just wondering that everything is perfectly done but still it's not working..so if you people can please take a look at this..!

and here is domain name to check please : www.bloggingdust.com

waiting for your replies..!

Comment: dude, It is redirecting for me

Comment: @yaqoob : Bro..the problem is that it redirects in firefox but not in chrome so may be you are using firefox that's why it is redirecting there..!

Comment: Ok, Tested in Chrome, IE9, Firefox they all redirects www :/

Comment: @yaqoob : Buddy you are not understanding infact...just remove the www. after loading blog and then click enter to load it again without www. then you will see that it doesn't load..!

Comment: done that, Even used proxy, its redirecting to www ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i Digg the domain name with Digwebinterface.

```
bloggingdust.com@ns1.dnsowl.com.:
bloggingdust.com.   7207    IN  A   74.125.20.121
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns1.dnsowl.com.
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns2.dnsowl.com.
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns3.dnsowl.com.
bloggingdust.com@ns2.dnsowl.com.:
bloggingdust.com.   7207    IN  A   74.125.20.121
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns1.dnsowl.com.
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns2.dnsowl.com.
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns3.dnsowl.com.
bloggingdust.com@ns3.dnsowl.com.:
bloggingdust.com.   7207    IN  A   74.125.20.121
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns1.dnsowl.com.
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns2.dnsowl.com.
bloggingdust.com.   172800  IN  NS  ns3.dnsowl.com.
```

The above A records aren't the same as suggested by Blogger. Check your `A` records accordingly and match them with these.

```
bloggingdust.com.       36000   IN  A   216.239.36.21
bloggingdust.com.       36000   IN  A   216.239.38.21
bloggingdust.com.       36000   IN  A   216.239.34.21
bloggingdust.com.       36000   IN  A   216.239.32.21
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but feel this question would be better sent to blogger.

If you perform an NSLOOKUP on the domain name you will retrieve the IP address or names that the initial name resolves to.

In doing so, I noticed that your name " bloggingdust.com resolves to 198.199.112.47, however your subdomain www.bloggingdust.com resolves to 74.125.20.121.

I would advise that you contact blogger or your DNS provider to address the issue if you are not confident at correcting DNS issues yourself, or if doing so does not fix the issue.

Gui

Comment: I just purchased this domain from namesilo.com and there they have already default created templates for different servers like blogger,weebly etc so I selected blogger and that set my "A" Record to  198.199.112.47 this IP...automaticaly..I don't know..how it recognized or from where this IP..so next suggestion..!